# String handling in C++

Tags: c++, string

How do I write a function in C++ that takes a string `s` and an integer `n` as input and gives at output a string that has spaces placed every `n` characters in `s`?

For example, if the input is `s = "abcdefgh"` and `n = 3` then the output should be `"abc def gh"`

EDIT:

I could have used loops for this but I am looking for concise and an idiomatic C++ solution (i.e. the one that uses algorithms from STL).

EDIT:

Here's how I would I do it in Scala (which happens to be my primary language):

```
def drofotize(s: String, n: Int) = s.grouped(n).toSeq.flatMap(_ + " ").mkString
```

Is this level of conciseness possible with C++? Or do I have to use explicit loops after all?

Comment: homework? please tag it as such if that's the case.

Comment: LOL. Homework? I got my degree in 1994. :D It's just that I am new to C++ and thus not acquainted with all its libraries very well.

Comment: Where'd you get it? Toys'R'Us? Sorry, couldn't resist. Seriously though, I'd add a little more, like are we talking STL strings here, or plain old null terminated char arrays?

Comment: Even people with an academic degree can study further and thus actually get homeworks.

Comment: @Paul, STL strings, of course. And I want STL solutions only. (The language tag reads C++, not C.)

Comment: @PeterK: Homework of this sort?!

Comment: @Daniel: There is std::string.insert(), std::string.substring(). Also I think you'll find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/c-how-to-split-a-string

Comment: Oh thanks @SigTerm, that looks interesting :)

Comment: @Daniel: doing a quick search on homework here on SO will reveal much stranger homeworks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy each character in a loop and when `i>0 && i%(n+1)==0` add extra space in the destination string.

---

As for Standard Library you could write your own `std::back_inserter` which will add extra spaces and then you could use it as follows:

```
std::copy( str1.begin(), str1.end(), my_back_inserter(str2, n) );
```

but I could say that writing such a functor is just a wasting of your time. It is much simpler to write a function `copy_with_spaces` with an old good for-loop in it.

Comment: Are you kidding me? Do you really think I can't even develop a looping logic? I want a more idiomatic (read: the one that uses STL) solution and that's why I posted the question here.

Comment: @Daniel, you didn't even mentioned about STL in your original question. What are you really looking for? Could you be more specific in your question?

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks. :) (Just add an EDIT after your first paragraph so that people know what's new and what was there in the original post.)

Answer (score 2):

STL algorithms don't really provide anything like this. Best I can think of:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string drofotize(const string &s, size_t n)
{
    if (s.size() <= n)
    {
        return s;
    }
    return s.substr(0,n) + " " + drofotize(s.substr(n), n);
}
```

Comment: Tail-recursive solution. Nice!

Comment: We may be stuck in C++, but that doesn't mean we can't be civilized. ;)